# Activity doesn't start when clicked on the notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I created a notification setup in my application.when the user clicks the notification an activity `Coding` is suppose to open.But it isn't.When i checked the phone log(in the console of the android studio) it has some thing like this in it:

`10-19 19:18:14.598 888-1437/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x1000c000 cmp=com.defcomdevs.invento16/.Coding bnds=[0,874][1080,1060] } from null (pid=-1, uid=10169) not exported from uid 10185`

i don't understand what that is?
my code for notification is:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static int notifyId=1;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm has been set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotify=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mNotify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.index);
    mNotify.setContentTitle("Coding");
    mNotify.setContentText("INVENTO: Coding competition is going to be conducted today.");
    Intent resultIntent=new Intent(context,Coding.class); //activity to open up when user clicks the notification
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Coding.class); //add the to-be-displayed activity to the top of stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNotify.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notifyId, mNotify.build());
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
    r.play();
    //note: on click display activity is not working.
}
}
```

please help!!

My `manifest.xml` file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.defcomdevs.invento16" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlarmActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Registration"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Coding"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coding"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you also include your manifest.xml file?

Comment: @GSala i have added my manifest file.

Comment: So I think you could fix this adding `android:exported="true"`inside the activity tag in the manifest. But, I don't think this is the best solution because it means other apps could start your activity. Also, I'm suspicious about the `android:process":remote"` tag in the receiver. Maybe you can't start the activity from another process without the exported tag. I would try to remove `android:process":remote"` from the receiver first.

Comment: Sir,removing `android:process":remote"` doesn't work.Still the same.Also i want to point out that this has worked once before after that i made some changes like adding a shared preference but that is a separate activity and has no connections with this one.And also i added the ringtone for the notification.Can that cause this problem?

Comment: I don't think the ringtone can cause the problem. Have you tried setting `android:exported:"true"` just to try and identify the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry sir, still not working. I have tried `android:exported="true"`.

Comment: Well, I thought this would fix it. If that's not it, I have no idea... Just to make sure, the exported tag was supposed to be inside the activity tag that you want to start, not the receiver.

Comment: Okay that solved as you pointed out i wrongly placed that tag inside my receiver thank you.

Comment: Added as a response for others to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:exported="true"` to your `.Coding` activity tag in the `manifest.xml`file. Though have in mind that this allows other applications to start your activity.